# How do I cache requests using RXjs?

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5, rxjs6

The situation is as follows:
There is a text. Every text change, and I submit a request. 
The response text is divided into parts.
Then I send each part to the server again.

Example:

Request - Response
**1234567 => [1], [2], [3,4], [5, 6, 7]**
Request Queue
**[1] => [2] => [3,4] => [5,6,7]**

Change the text

Request - Response
**12334567 => [1], [2], [3,3,4], [5, 6, 7]**

Here I want to compare prev answer with new one, to send only
**[3, 3, 4]**

I decided to make it all as stream, and finally deal with RxJS.
Actually looking for RxJS way

Comment: Could you add example code of implementation that you have tried so far?

Comment: Are you using Angular? I wrote a library for dealing with application state using RxJs observables. https://medium.com/@adrianbrand/angular-state-management-with-rxcache-468a865fc3fb

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest an alternative here. Instead of caching the response array, cache the response of HTTP request you make using an **Interceptor**. Simple **map** will be a good choice for a cache. If you are using Angular see the code below, it provides Intercepts out of the box.

If you make an HTTP request for **[1]** for example save it in a cache

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {

   const response = this.cache.get(req); // get the cached response object.

   return response? Observable.of(response) : makeHttpRequest(req,next)
}

makeRequest(req, next){
 //make http request and save it in cache as well,
 const response = httpREquest();
 this.cache.put(req, response);
}
```

From your example when request for **[3,3,4]** is made, no output in cache found, make an http request and save it. This way you will avoid array comparison.